# Correct way to wrap a c++ structure that contains a char[] in c++/cli?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, wrapper

I am trying to right a c++/cli wrapper around some c++ code I inherited for contolling some lab equipment so that I can call the code from the other .net languages. I have a few questions that I have not been unable to find an answer to. The c++ code defines something along the lines of:

```
typedef struct{
    bool val;
    /* Some more c++ fundamental types ...*/

    char char_array[32];
    unsigned char unsigned_char_array[128];
    RECT rect;
} UnmangedStruct, *LpUnmanagedStruct;
```

My wrapper structure is follows:

```
public ref structure ManagedStruct{
    bool val;
    /* Some more c++ fundamental types ...*/

    System::String^ char_array;
    System::String^ unsigned_char_array;
    System::Drawing::Rectangle disp_rect;
}
```

I am know trying to write some helper function to convert between the two structures.

Questions:

1) What does the *LpUnmanagedStruct do? Does it initalize a new instance of this structure and point *LpUnmanaged at it?

2) Is String^ the right managed type to wrap char[] and unsigned char[]? RECT <-> Rectangle?

3) And the main thing I want to know is how you convert String^ or whatever the right type is for wrapping a char[] / unsigned char[] and vice versa when only char* can be passed in and returned from a function. I have seen in numerious posts that you should just convert everything to use char* but I really don't want to modify the original c++ if I can help it.

Comment: You are not wrapping anything.  The char_array member should be a property instead that uses the unmanaged member.  And have a better name :)  And throw an exception in the setter when the string doesn't fit.  Use `ref class` instead so you can hide the native struct with *private*.  If you wrap a pointer to the struct instead of the struct itself then you need a destructor and finalizer.

Comment: Using C++/CLI when you don't even know normal C and C++ yet is only going to end in pain.  But [this C++/CLI smart pointer I wrote can help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object), that way you won't have to write the disposer and finalizer Hans mentioned by hand.  (.NET types don't have destructors, only `Dispose` and `Finalize`)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks again Hans. I will combine your suggestions and the suggestions from the answer bellow and see if I can get something working. And will add the working code as an edit below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said in the comments, if you don't already know C++, C++/CLI is not going to end well. **C++/CLI has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and some complexities all its own thrown in.**

That said, here's my thoughts on this problem.

If you're writing a C++/CLI wrapper to manually convert between the two structures, then what you want to do is to declare the managed type with the most natural typed members you can. So for example, declare the managed type with `String^`, and handle the conversion to `char[]` manually.

(You need to care a lot more about how you declare a managed struct if you're going to be doing marshalling & P/Invoking. In that case, you need to declare everything just so, so that the automatic marshalling produces the right bytes in the output. But since you said 'wrapper', I take that to mean that you'll be doing the managed to unmanaged conversion manually, and we don't need to worry about that.)

So, let's go through the fields of the struct:

- `char char_array[]`: As you noted, this is probably a string, so the `String^` type is appropriate.
- `unsigned char unsigned_char_array[128]`: Look at how this member is used, and what its real name is. This might be a string, or it might be binary data, which would be a `List<System::Byte>`, or an `array<System::Byte>`.
- `RECT`: `System::Drawing::Rectangle` looks good, but just be careful when you write the conversion method: `RECT` uses left/right/top/bottom, while `System::Drawing::Rectangle` uses x/y/width/height. Just use the right accessors & conversion methods on `System::Drawing::Rectangle`. You may also want to consider one of the other rectangle classes in the .Net library: For example, if you're going to use that rectangle in a WPF GUI, you might want to use `System.Windows.Rectangle` instead.

Other notes:

- That typedef declares two types: `UnmangedStruct`, and `LpUnmanagedStruct`, which is a pointer to an `UnmangedStruct`. I've never really understood why we need a separate declared type to refer to a pointer to a struct (`UnmangedStruct*` always seemed sufficient to me), but that is a standard pattern.
- I *HIGHLY* recommend that you declare this as `ref class`, for two reasons:

  - What you want here is a managed class, not a managed struct. You should only use managed structs for the simplest things, and even then it's recommended that it be immutable. Managed mutable structs are rarely what you want when interfacing with C#.
  - You already have a managed class, not a managed struct: A managed struct is `value class` or `value struct`, while a managed class is `ref class` or `ref struct`. I recommend only using `value struct` or `ref class`, because the other ones are easily mistaken.
- To handle the actual encoding, there's no method that I can find in the .Net library that will go directly from `String^` to an already existing `char[]`. (They either take something else as a parameter, or return a managed byte array.) What I'd do is use `std::string` as an intermediary: Do `marshal_as<std::string>(managedString)`, then do a plain `strcpy` to the `char[]`. For the other direction, pass the char array directly to the method that takes a `char*`: `marshal_as<String^>(char_array)`.
- You **must** write a Dispose and Finalize method on your managed class to deallocate any unmanaged memory that was allocated with `new` or `malloc`.

  ```
  ~ManagedStruct() { delete foo; free(bar); delete managed_idisposable_baz; } // Dispose method
  !ManagedStruct() { delete foo; free(bar); } // Finalize method
  ```

  Or use the helper class that Ben Voigt mentioned in the comments.